# i can't run a flutter app on android studio emulator

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

i'm having a problem running the flutter app on the androidstudio emulator

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find gradle-7.3.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.3.0/gradle-7.3.0.jar
   > Could not find builder-7.3.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:7.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/7.3.0/builder-7.3.0.jar
   > Could not find bundletool-1.9.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.9.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/1.9.0/bundletool-1.9.0.jar
   > Could not find protos-30.3.0.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:30.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/30.3.0/protos-30.3.0.jar

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

i tried updating java and it gave me an error

Comment: Have you tried installing the proper gradle version?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try these

Check if your `Gradle plugin` version and `Kotlin` version used in your project are compatible with each other.

And

Check your `Java SDK` if it compatible with the `Gradle plugin` version

if not change the `Java SDK` or `Gradle plugin` accordingly

Then run the Gradle build.

I hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: i ran gradle -v and this is what came out
```
 ------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.5
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-07-14 12:48:15 UTC
Revision:     c7db7b958189ad2b0c1472b6fe663e6d654a5103

Kotlin:       1.6.21
Groovy:       3.0.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          17.0.8 (Oracle Corporation 17.0.8+9-LTS-211)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64 ```
```
i already tried changing jdk from 1.8 to 21 and 17
 i don't know if they are compatible or not

Comment: @MayarIsm you can also try gradlew clean and gradlew build from the android folder in the terminal